# Azure APIM changing virtual network type - forces replacement [Terraform]

Tags: terraform, azure-api-management, azure-virtual-network, terraform-provider-azure

I deployed an `APIM` as `External` through `terraform`.

Now i wanted to change the virtual networking type to `internal`.

However when i do so , terrform initiates force Replacement and my APIM instnace is getting replaced.

How to script it in terraform  - so that it only `updates` and not `force replacement`

**update**
Even `None` to `Internal` - forces replacement
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can move from None to External or None to Internal, otherwise it is a froced replacement. It is not documented.  You can see the [code reference](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/azurerm/internal/services/apimanagement/api_management_resource.go#L471).  It is a limitation of the API and there is an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues/10395).

> (Paraphrasing) The reason is the subnet cannot be destroyed because “InUseSubnetCannotBeDeleted” for 3 hours. Further you cannot
> change the subnet from subnet1 to subnet2 either, because subnet1 is
> in state “InUseSubnetCannotBeDeleted” for 3 hours.

Comment: I have updated the question. Still forces replacement.

Comment: Provide full code and full output including versions